# Model return List object

Tags: c#

I have a ViewModel where objects are all `string` and the model from the database `Address` is a list. I wanted to know if there is any other way to set the viewModel string values other then the way I have it done below? Any advice on how to make this code; cleaner, more effective, just overall better!

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //EF Data
            List<Address> ListOfProducts = new List<Address>();
            ListOfProducts.Add(new Address() { StreetLine1="address 1",StreetLine2="address line2 1" });
            ViewModelAddress vm = new ViewModelAddress();
            vm.StreetLine1 = ListOfProducts.Select(a => a.StreetLine1).FirstOrDefault();
            vm.StreetLine2 = ListOfProducts.Select(a => a.StreetLine2).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        class Address
        {
            public string StreetLine1 { get; set; }
            public string StreetLine2{ get; set; }
        }
        class ViewModelAddress
        {
            public string StreetLine1 { get; set; }
            public string StreetLine2 { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is confusing.

```
List<Address> ListOfProducts = new List<Address>();
```

Should it be

```
List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
```

The example you have provided is rather simple. Since the view model is exactly the same as the source object you might as well use an anonymous type and just not include the properties you do not want to see in the view model.

```
static string Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
    addresses.Add(new Address() { StreetLine1 = "address 1", StreetLine2 = "address line2 1", Postcode = "pstc0d3" });

    // no postcode
    var vm = addresses.Select(_ => new { _.StreetLine1, _.StreetLine2 }).FirstOrDefault();
}

class Address
{
    public string StreetLine1 { get; set; }
    public string StreetLine2 { get; set; }

    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

The variable vm will have the properties StreetLine1 and StreetLine2.